# Access a strong name key (pfk) password in an AfterBuild event

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, strong-named-key

If strong name signing an assembly with a password protected pfk is it possible to get access to the password used for the key in an AfterBuild node?

Comment: The password is not stored nor accessible by anyone, it's just used once to install the certificate durably in a container (like the wizard when you double click on the .pfx file from Explorer). More on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658541/enumerating-container-names-of-the-strong-name-csp. (see the VS_KEY_* containers). Perhalps it would help if you tell us hat are you trying to do exactly in the end?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to get the password.