# Enumerating container names of the strong name CSP

Tags: .net, strong-named-key

I'm trying to find some information about how to (if at all possible) enumerate all container names in the Strong Name CSP (Cryptographic Service Provider).

Essentially, when you type `sn.exe -i key.snk MyContainerName`, the public and private key pairs are stored into what's called a "container". Later, within your code, you could specify the container name in the [`AssemblyKeyNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblykeynameattribute.aspx), e.g.:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("MyContainerName")]
```

This will cause the assembly to be signed at compile time.

I am trying to find out if it's possible to somehow enumerate all container names. I'm writing a [plugin for ReSharper](https://github.com/hmemcpy/ReSharper.InternalsVisibleTo) that provides code completion for the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. I'd also like to provide code completion for the `AssemblyKeyName` attribute, where I would pre-populate the list with known container names.

Is this information accessible?

**EDIT:** From a comment on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-can-i-enumerate-all-the-saved-rsa-keys-in-the-microsoft-csp) at IT Security StackExchange, there's a link to a little util called [KeyPal](http://www.jensign.com/KeyPal/index.html). Running this utility with `LM` will dump the local machine key store:

> ```
> --------- KeyPal:  MACHINE store: 3 keycontainers ---------
> [0] VS_KEY_F726FDF898BC4CB8
>      Signature 1024
> [1] IIS Express Development Certificate Container
>      Exchange  1024
>      CertE: CN=localhost
> [2] MyContainerName
>      Signature 1024
> -------------------------------------------------
> ```

Where I can see that both [0] and [2] are valid container names to use with `AssemblyKeyName`. However, there's the [1] one - "IIS Express...", which is not a valid container. How do I distinguish between them?

Comment: Not solving the actual problem, but in case it helps... You know in general specifying via Attributes is deprecated (as in you'll struggle to see it outside of V1.1 codebases) in favor of VS managing the installation into the store and the passing them to the CSC Task? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16464894/11635)

Comment: @RubenBartelink Interesting, thanks. I assumed as much, since there's barely any up-to-date info about these things. I'm only doing this out of interest, since a user of my ReSharper plugin reported a bug, and in his case they're still using the attributes. So I wondered how difficult it would be to "assist" them. But, it does look like anybody barely uses it anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is sample code that kinda does the same thing as that keypal tool. It enumerates all containers (for the local machine) and from there gets the one that can become [StrongNameKeyPairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.strongnamekeypair.aspx). Usually, strong name keys have a 160 bytes-length public key (SHA1):

```
foreach (var kc in KeyUtilities.EnumerateKeyContainers("Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider"))
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = kc;
    cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider prov = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
    {
        if (prov.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable)
        {
            var blob = prov.ExportCspBlob(true);
            StrongNameKeyPair kp = new StrongNameKeyPair(prov.ExportCspBlob(false));
            Console.WriteLine(kc + " pk length:" + kp.PublicKey.Length);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

...

```
public static class KeyUtilities
{
    public static IList<string> EnumerateKeyContainers(string provider)
    {
        ProvHandle prov;
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(out prov, null, provider, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET | CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        IntPtr data = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            int flag = CRYPT_FIRST;
            int len = 0;
            if (!CryptGetProvParam(prov, PP_ENUMCONTAINERS, IntPtr.Zero, ref len, flag))
            {
                if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
            do
            {
                if (!CryptGetProvParam(prov, PP_ENUMCONTAINERS, data, ref len, flag))
                {
                    if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                        break;

                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }

                list.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(data));
                flag = CRYPT_NEXT;
            }
            while (true);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (data != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(data);
            }

            prov.Dispose();
        }
        return list;
    }

    private sealed class ProvHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public ProvHandle()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CryptReleaseContext(handle, 0);
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CryptReleaseContext(IntPtr hProv, int dwFlags);

    }

    const int PP_ENUMCONTAINERS = 2;
    const int PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
    const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
    const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259;
    const int CRYPT_FIRST = 1;
    const int CRYPT_NEXT = 2;
    const int CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x20;
    const int CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = unchecked((int)0xF0000000);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(out ProvHandle phProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, int dwProvType, int dwFlags);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CryptGetProvParam(ProvHandle hProv, int dwParam, IntPtr pbData, ref int pdwDataLen, int dwFlags);
}
```

The following Namespaces are referenced:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks! I recently modified my little plugin to read the snk files direct using some utils from Roslyn. I might incorporate some of your code into it as well (with proper attribution, of course!)